# XAML load and serialize to an object

Tags: c#, .net, xaml

i everybody i have a strange problem.
What i whould like to do is to use XAML features by loading an xaml with

var test = (StructureFile)XamlServices.Load(reader); 
(Console application)

what i actually have is the StructureFile

```
[RuntimeNameProperty("StructureFile")]
    [ContentProperty("Build")]
    public class StructureFile
    {
        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

        public StructureFile()
        {
            Items = new List<Item>();
        }
    }
```

and

```
 public class Item 
    {
        public string Call {get; set;}
        public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

the xaml file loocks something like this:

```
<StructureFile  xmlns="clr-namespace:SoSafeIP;assembly=blah" 
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib" 
                xmlns:my="clr-namespace:BindingXAML"
xmlns:Extentions="clr-Namespace:BuildFunctions.BuildExtenstions;assembly=BuildAddon">
  <StructureFile.Items>
    <scg:List x:TypeArguments="Item" Capacity="4">
      <Item Call="{Extentions:CreateChangeLog}" Items="{x:Null}" />
```

what i'm getting in here is an Exception

> 'Cannot create unknown type
>   '{clr-namespace:BuildFunctions.BuildExtenstions;assembly=BuildAddon}CreateChangeLog'.'
>   Line number '11' and line position '13'.

i even added the BuildAddon dll as a referenz (actually if this will work i ahould like to inject it with an IOC container) but for the first i need to make this work first..

any ideas?